# Python & SQL - Python wont actually commit data to SQL DB

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x

This is a 2 part question but Ill get to my first conundrum.

I have some code I'm just trying to test where I want Python to run a stored procedure with the required variables and it runs and even shows the new row. However, if I go into the DB and run a SELECT statement to show me the data, its not there. Its as if the DB blocked it or something strange.

This code WORKS if I run a select statement instead of this stored procedure. The stored procedure works and even when I run this code, Python will run the stored procedure and spit back the new row (complete with the new row number that's auto-generated due to the IDENTITY I have on the column)

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=REPORT\INSTANCE;'
                      'UID=UserID;'
                      'PWD=Password;'
                      'Database=ReportDB;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=no;')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('EXEC [Schema].[Comments] \'2019-04-18 00:00:00.000\',\'Team\',\'1900-01-01 13:12:16.000\',\'testing this string\',\'username\'')


for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

Kind of lost here. Python will run the stored procedure (which I have set to run a select at the end of, to prove the data was committed) and Python shows that but I don't see it in the actual DB. That line is gone.

[image: This is the result after running stored procedure in Python]

You can see here, the 470 is the ID Column (Identity, no null) and that's what it should be.

[image: Here is the SQL run right after]

Notice that the most recent entry is still 469

- Same Instance
- Same DB

**EDIT**

I just noticed something in the Python. Each time I run the Python code, it runs the code and the stored procedure does the select at the end but each time I run it, the `CommentsID` increases by 1 (as it should) but its NOT remembering the previous ones inserted by Python. The only ones the SELECT statement pulls back in is the one I committed via SQL itself.

[image]

Notice here that the CommentsID (the first number in each line that starts with a 4) goes from 469 to 471. Yet I just had that image above that shows 470 - where did 470 go?!

Second part:

I'm having a hard time putting variables into that EXEC section of the code. I think I need to wrap it in single quotes which means I need to put \ in front of the quotes I need to stay for the SQL code. But when I do that and then try to run it, I cant get it to pull in the variables.

Here is what the SQL needs to be:

```
EXEC [schema].[Comments] 'Username'
```

In Python, I know I need it to be in single quotes but because the SQL code has quotes, you typically just put \ in front like this:

```
'EXEC [schema].[Comments] \'Username\''
```

That works. However, I then want username to pull from a variable, not be a string.

Comment: ...are you sure you're looking at the same database/server?

Comment: I am not familiar with Python, but do you need something like cnxn.commit()?

Comment: If you see it in the SELECT *at the end of it*, the data is there; if it wasn't, the SELECT couldn't show it. *Second part* is a separate question. In both cases (the SPROC that you didn't include code for and the code where you're trying to include variables), we can't help you debug code that we cannot see in your question.

Comment: @RobertPaulsen   - yes, SQL is actually where my specialty lands. I did go back to check my work but its definitely all of the same server/database.

Comment: @KenWhite Right? Thats why I have that select there. Its pretty baffling. I wish I could show you what Im seeing.

Comment: @KenWhite Ill add some sample code to it.

Comment: @RobertPaulsen You were right! I did need to do conn.commit(). I didnt see that in any documentation for pyodbc.

Now I can go back to working on the second half.

Comment: Awesome! Now you can get back to doing Real Work (TM).